# UIPanGestureRecognizer never call action method

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, action, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to my `mapView` but I don't why **the action method is never called** (Swift 2.1).

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    { 
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // other stuff...

        let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didDragMap:")
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    func didDragMap(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        // never enter here
    }
}
```

What's wrong here? I have the same Objective-C corresponding and it's work.

Comment: Try printing `mapView.gestureRecognizers`--perhaps there's another pan recognizer already attached? You could try putting a transparent view above your map view and attaching a pan recognizer to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an MKMapView already handles it's own gestures you need to enable it to also listen to your gestures.

Implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` and return true like so:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)